# Rails and Mysql2 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I am somewhat new to Rails, and much of my experience involves me feeling out how to work out the problem so I apologize in advance if I have missed and obvious solution. I run a Windows machine.

I am creating a log-in and registration using mysql2. MySQL installer has already been used to install the server, workbench, etc. (I configured the root password as password) and I have already installed the mysql2 gem.

The rails was bundled successfully but when I entered `rake db:create`, the error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` occurred.

Rails then prompted me for my password, I entered it but the error occurred again. After entering my password the second time, it seemed as if it worked fine until I tried to do a `rails db:migrate` wherein the error appeared again making it not possible to migrate.

This confuses me because in the MySQL query, I have my password set as the same one I entered. I tried giving the 'root' user all the schema privileges, but that made no difference. Please tell me how to solve this problem and thank you.

If you have any questions about my question, please ask.

Answer (score 31):

for me helped

```
$ mysql -u root -p

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypassword')
```

and in databse.yml

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
database: mydb
host: localhost
username: root
password: "mypassword" #I had an empty string here before
```

thanks to @spongezh22

Comment: Same problem if your password starts with the ! character.

Comment: @zombie_ghast It doesn't work for me. It still asks a password when I run mysql -u root -p
password is same as I set during installation. please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Don't forget your semicolon for: SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypassword');

Answer (score 9):

seems like your user cannot connect to the mysql DB, try this commands in your console

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and when prompted give the password as 'admin'

if this is possible then you should be good to go

And you database yml file should be like

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: mydb
 host: localhost
 username: root
 password: mypass
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to of fixed the migration but now I changed the routes file to  `Login::Application.routes.draw do  
  resources :users  
  get '/register'   
  root 'users#index'`    and when I did `rails s` , a large error occured

Comment: The error is too large for the comment size but I tried reinstalling everything and when I created a fresh program with mysql and did `rails s` , the browser shows Mysql2::Error  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  Rails.root: C:/Sites/rails_projects/practice . I would assume I have missed doing something in the Mysql workbench but I am not sure what it could be.  @Bharatsoni

Comment: My Mysql workbench has the command `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypassword')`  if this information helps

Answer (score 2):

Running `./bin/spring stop` fixed for me. I found it in a Github, but can't remember where.

Answer (score 1):

I just copied and pasted the above (below) to my rails yml file and it worked!!

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
database: mydb
host: localhost
username: root
password: mypass
```

Answer (score 1):

Rake try in fact to create your `test` database as well, that's why you get the error message if you do not set correctly your `test` database credentials like (database.yml)

```
default: &default
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: atheneum
    pool: 5
    username: ******
    password: "******"
    host: localhost


development:
  <<: *default
  database: atheneum

test:
  <<: *default
  database: atheneum_test
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was due to the password starting with "!". Changing my password in mysql and database.yml solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was just an incorrect database password that was in the database.yml file. I changed the password and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the few occasions where I had to restart the rails server after I made changes to the database.yml file. After I set the password in the file, I had to restart the rails server. After that the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Not a rails answer, but for others showing up here:

If you are passing in your own credentials somehow, perhaps an ENV file to a standalone script, be sure that you don't have any invisible characters like a '\n' at the end of your password. That'll really mess with you.

Answer (score 0):

Error was saying that Access denied for user root. (I had no password).
My problem was for the reason that i've changed the default 3306 port to 8111. In database.yml ive added 
`port: 8111`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't remember setting your password, do this:

```
sudo mysql -u root

use mysql;

UPDATE user set authentication_string='MyPassword' where user='root';
```

This will update your password. Then, change the **database/config.yml** file to match your password.

(Depending on the version of MySQL you're running, you might have to surround the 'password' with a PASSWORD() function or a sha2() function)

Answer (score -1):

On advise of Bhrat above I created my linux user as a user in mysql.
ensured that user can connect from $user
changed user from root in database yml to user
rake db:create worked